# context menu demo app not working crossrider

Tags: contextmenu, crossrider

I am generating context menu when user selects some text and right click it. I tried implementing it, problem is even sample application is not working.

http://crossrider.com/apps/10565/ide

```
appAPI.contextMenu.add("key1", "Display data object", function (data) {
   var sAlertText = 'pageUrl: ' + data.pageUrl + '\r\n' +
                 'linkUrl: ' + data.linkUrl + '\r\n' +
                 'selectedText:' + data.selectedText + '\r\n' +
                 'srcUrl:' + data.srcUrl;
   alert(sAlertText);
}, ["all"]);
```

Only `data.pageUrl` is available rest of all are "undefined". I want selectedText.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Disclaimer: I work at Crossrider.

Indeed there was an issue with the contextMenu due to a change in the Chrome API. 
We've fixed this and now the demo app works.

Thank you for reporting this and please feel free to let us know if you encounter any issues!

Amir